# Using a SQL minus operation in PROGRESS 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

is there a way to make what is equivalent of a minus operation from SQL in Progress? I have 2 selects and want the first minus the second.
For example, originally in SQL something like this:

```
select id from item
minus
select id from item-uni
```

I'm trying to do it like this in Progress

```
DEF TEMP-TABLE tt-item NO-UNDO
FIELD item-id    AS INT
FIELD desc       AS CHAR
.

DEF TEMP-TABLE tt-item2 NO-UNDO
FIELD item-id    AS INT
FIELD desc       AS CHAR
.


FOR EACH item-uni
WHERE item-uni.desc = '101':

        CREATE tt-item.
        ASSIGN
        tt-item.item-id   = item-uni.item-id
        tt-item.desc = item-uni.desc
        .
END.

   FOR EACH item:

        CREATE tt-item2.
        ASSIGN
        tt-item2.item-id   = item.item-id
        tt-item2.desc = item.desc
        .
END.



FOR EACH tt-item,
    EACH tt-item2
    WHERE tt-item.item-id = tt-item2.item-id:

            DELETE tt-item.
    END.
```

When I try to do this, however, I receive an error message. Is there an easy way (or at least easier) to do this? Thanks.

Comment: An error message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading what `minus` is supposed to do, ie return all rows from the outer select for which no row exists on the inner select, then this should do:

```
for each item
   where not can-find( 
            item-uni 
               where item-uni.id = item.id
         )
no-lock:

   /* do something */

end.
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Sorry if I wasn't very clear but you have taught me precisely what I wanted. I didn't know about this can-find function. Thanks.

Comment: if id is not unique in item-uni, you'd need not can-find(first ...) .

Answer (score 0):

It's been some days since I posted because only now I managed to get a good and correct answer. I had to use NOT CAN-FIND in an IF clause in order for it to work.
The first temp-table gets the values I want, the second one sees which of these values are on the table I don't want to. The third iteration is where the NOT CAN-FIND is, making it like the 'minus' I wanted to use. It became like this:

```
IF NOT CAN-FIND (tt-item-temp2
            WHERE tt-item-temp2.item-id = tt-item-temp.item-id) THEN DO:
```

Once again, i'd like to thank you Stefan. If not for you, I'd not find this answer.